# Serialize or Hash a Closure in PHP

Tags: php, serialization, closures

This is bound to beg design questions, but I want to serialize or hash a closure in PHP such that I have a unique identifier for that closure.

I don't need to be able to call the closure from that, I just need a unique identifier for it that is accessible from inside and outside of the closure itself, i.e. a method that accepts a closer will need to generate an id for that closure, and the closure itself will need to be able to generate that same id

Things I've tried so far:

```
$someClass = new SomeClass();

$closure1 = $someClass->closure();

print $closure1();
// Outputs: I am a closure: {closure}

print $someClass->closure();
// Outputs: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

print serialize($closure1);
// Outputs: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed'

class SomeClass
{
    function closure()
    {
        return function () { return 'I am a closure: ' . __FUNCTION__; };
    }
}
```

The Reflection API doesn't seem to offer anything I might be able to use to create an ID either.

Comment: Well, consider your design questioned ;) "Closure" is an anonymous function here?

Comment: Yes a closure is an anonymous function...I still want a way to make a hash of it though ;)

Comment: in which scope is this hash to be unique?

Comment: I need to be able to obtain the hash from within the closure itself, and from within a method that accepts the closure as a paramater

Comment: yes I got that but "how long" does it have to be unique? to you want eg. to persist it in a DB?

Comment: It only needs to be unique in the scope of an instance - nothing will be persisted

Comment: If you do not need serialization and this is all in one request, try with [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/spl_object_hash).

Comment: @hakre you pointed it out but it is important to stress that this indeed only works within the **same** request. The hashes cannot be stored and used later. It is not clear from the OP if this is a requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution is more general and respects static parameters for closure. To make the trick, you can pass a reference to the closure inside the closure:

```
class ClosureHash
{
    /**
     * List of hashes
     *
     * @var SplObjectStorage
     */
    protected static $hashes = null;

    /**
     * Returns a hash for closure
     *
     * @param callable $closure
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function from(Closure $closure)
    {
        if (!self::$hashes) {
            self::$hashes = new SplObjectStorage();
        }

        if (!isset(self::$hashes[$closure])) {
            $ref  = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
            $file = new SplFileObject($ref->getFileName());
            $file->seek($ref->getStartLine()-1);
            $content = '';
            while ($file->key() < $ref->getEndLine()) {
                $content .= $file->current();
                $file->next();
            }
            self::$hashes[$closure] = md5(json_encode(array(
                $content,
                $ref->getStaticVariables()
            )));
        }
        return self::$hashes[$closure];
    }
}

class Test {

    public function hello($greeting)
    {
        $closure = function ($message) use ($greeting, &$closure) {
            echo "Inside: ", ClosureHash::from($closure), PHP_EOL, "<br>" ;
        };
        return $closure;
    }
}

$obj = new Test();

$closure = $obj->hello('Hello');
$closure('PHP');
echo "Outside: ", ClosureHash::from($closure), PHP_EOL, "<br>";

$another = $obj->hello('Bonjour');
$another('PHP');
echo "Outside: ", ClosureHash::from($another), PHP_EOL, "<br>";
```

Answer (score 6):

You could all that you need write your own, your own closures having a `getId()` or `getHash()` or whatever.

Example ([Demo](http://eval.in/5103)):

```
1: Hello world
2: Hello world
```

First closure (ID: 1), ID read in calling context. Second closure (ID: 2), ID read from within the closure (where self-reference).

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983714/serialize-or-hash-a-closure-in-php
 */

class IdClosure
{
    private $callback;
    private $id;

    private static $sequence = 0;

    final public function __construct(Callable $callback) {
        $this->callback = $callback;
        $this->id = ++IdClosure::$sequence;
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        return call_user_func_array($this->callback, func_get_args());
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

$hello = new IdClosure(function($text) { echo "Hello $text\n";});
echo $hello->getId(), ": ", $hello('world');

$hello2 = new IdClosure(function($text) use (&$hello2) { echo $hello2->getId(), ": Hello $text\n";} );
$hello2('world');
```

I have no clue if that suits your needs, maybe it gives you some ideas. I suggested `spl_object_hash` but didn't understood the discussion much why it does not or in the end then does work.

Comment: The problem is/was that the function spl_object_hash can return duplicate values if other object have already been destroyed and collected by the GC. This is because spl_object_hash is only unique for **existing** objects. (says so in the manual!) This may never happen, or it may happen a lot. I will depend strongly on the code, and so may produce weird effects.

Comment: @dualed: Yes, that behavior of `spl_object_hash` is known. You need to keep a collection of objects then to make use of the hashes, see as well: http://php.net/splobjectstorage

Comment: BTW: The implementation here does not have duplicate IDs for the closures.

Comment: Yes you are right, it follows more or less the same principle as my idea with $this-injection. I like your way better though because you can type-hint it. I don't understand however why you have to extend the class, you inject the callback anyway. I just don't see the benefit of the abstract class here

Comment: I extend the class to ensure that `IdBaseClosure::$id` *is* private and can not be modified from the outside. Otherwise the ID could be tainted and would render it useless. It's just to have this strict, better safe than sorry.

Comment: You can access private properties from outside of an object in PHP?

Comment: No, naturally not, that's why `private` is used here. Keep in mind that you can bind `$this` to closures so to give access to private members, however, with the abstract base-class this is prevented.

Comment: I see, for me that would throw `Fatal error: Cannot access private property Foo::$bar` though.

Comment: @dualed: Ah right, I probably was going a bit far off ;) Also the callback should be private as well. I updated the answer to correct that. Thanks for your feedback, I might have tried something different first and thats why I had it that way. But for the example given it looks superfluous I have to admit ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here is the only thing I can think of:

```
<?php
$f = function() {
};
$rf = new ReflectionFunction($f);
$pseudounique = $rf->getFileName().$rf->getEndLine();
?>
```

If you like, you can hash it with md5 or whatnot. If the function is generated from a string however, you should seed that with a `uniqid()`

Comment: are they defined in the same line?

Comment: Never mind last comment (deleted). This is the closest so far, I was working on something similar using Reflection with @hakre's suggestion of spl_object_hash() - I'll keep trying with that and if nothing comes of it I'll go with this, even though it seems a bit hacky

Comment: It is hacky, yes ;) tell me your target php version though, Idea incoming; or just tell me if php 5.4 is possible

Comment: I'm liking this...

`$someClass = new SomeClass();

$closure = $someClass->closure();
$closure2 = $someClass->closure2();

$rf = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
$rf2 = new ReflectionFunction($closure);

print spl_object_hash($rf); // Outputs: 000000007ddc37c8000000003b230216
print spl_object_hash($rf2); // Outputs: 000000007ddc37c9000000003b230216


class SomeClass
{
 function closure()
 {
  return function () { return 'I am closure: ' . __FUNCTION__; };
 }

 function closure2()
 {
  return function () { return 'I am closure: ' . __FUNCTION__; };
 }
}`

Answer (score 3):

PHP [anonymous functions](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) are exposed as instances of the [Closure class](http://php.net/class.closure).  As they're basically objects, [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/spl_object_hash) will return a unique identifier when handed one.  From the PHP interactive prompt:

```
php > $a = function() { echo "I am A!"; };
php > $b = function() { echo "I am B!"; };
php >
php >
php > echo spl_object_hash($a), "\n", spl_object_hash($b), "\n";
000000004f2ef15d000000003b2d5c60
000000004f2ef15c000000003b2d5c60
```

Those identifiers might *look* the same, but they differ by one letter in the middle.

The identifier is good only for that request, so expect it to change between calls, even if the function and any `use`'d variables don't change.

Comment: Yes, I did, and it gave me a fright.  I forgot that it likes adding the unique bit in the *middle* of the identifier instead of at the end.  I thought it was returning the same identifier every time, but was incorrect.  Phew!

Comment: I'm liking this, for some reason I thought I needed reflection to get the Closure object back (as in the solution I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13984282/360967), but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: interesting. I was there too, tried it and just re-ran the test. Two empty function always return the same hash

Comment: @dualed, that's what I thought as well, but I just re-tested with closures with no function body (`$x = function() {};`) and was unable to dupe.  Still getting a unique hash, with the letter incrementing in the middle.  Running 5.4.9 here...

Comment: hmm, I return the closures from a function, and testing `spl_object_hash(g()) == spl_object_hash(h())` definitely evals to true on my system

Comment: Perhaps it's an artifact of it being an object, and objects always being returned by reference?  PHP always has to get it *not quite right*...

Comment: I'm getting the same result as @Charles - spl_object_hash(function() {}) and spl_object_hash(function() {}) returns the same hash every time, but $fn = function() { }; $fn2 = function() { }; return different hashes

Comment: well I just had a suspicion... when I assign the return values of g() and h() to variables they are not equal anymore

Comment: We have a phrase at work when we encounter such an oddity.  "Why does that happen?  Because PHP, that's why."

Comment: Well I'm not a big fan of some PHP oddities either, but probably the function is just collected instantly and the 2nd generated at the same address

Comment: Must have something to do with the variable reference, using print spl_object_hash($someClass->closure()); and print spl_object_hash($someClass->closure2()); for the same functions described earlier (2 identical functions, no parameters no body), I get the same hash, assign the results of those two calls to variables, and they're different

Comment: @Toby: Yes, read the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) "Note: When an object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects." It's basically true of an address for an object too. Obviously, you should only compare hashes of objects that you know still exist.

Comment: Given that the hash can be reused within the request, I'm beginning to think the other technique using var_dump might be best, as then you get a *real* unique per-request object identifier...

Answer (score 2):

[Superclosure](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure) provides a convenience class that allows you to serialize/unserialize closures, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to generate a signature. Creating a signature from outside the closure will be nearly impossible to reproduce if the closure accepts any parameters. The data passed in will change the generated signature.

```
$someClass = new SomeClass();
$closure1 = $someClass->closure();
$closure1_id = md5(print_r($closure1, true));
```

Even if your closure doesn't accept parameters, you still have the problem of storing and persisting the signature inside the closure. You might be able to do something with a static variable inside the closure so it only initializes once and retains the "signature". But that gets messy on how to retrieve it.

It really sounds like you want a class, not a closure. It would solve all of these problems. You could pass in a "salt" on instantiation and have it generate a signature using the salt (i.e. a random number). That would make the signature unique. You could then retain that salt, recreate a class using the exact same constructor parameters (i.e. salt) and compare that with the signature on file in the already created class.

Comment: `var_dump` is probably a better idea here than `print_r`.  At least on my local copy, the output from `print_r` is always "Closure Object()", while the `var_dump` includes the object number.

Comment: agreed, var_dump would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution arrived at with the help of @hakre and @dualed:

```
$someClass = new SomeClass();

$closure = $someClass->closure();
$closure2 = $someClass->closure2();

$rf = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
$rf2 = new ReflectionFunction($closure2);

print spl_object_hash($rf); // Outputs: 000000007ddc37c8000000003b230216
print spl_object_hash($rf2); // Outputs: 000000007ddc37c9000000003b230216

class SomeClass
{
    function closure()
    {
        return function () { return 'I am closure: ' . __FUNCTION__; };
    }

    function closure2()
    {
        return function () { return 'I am closure: ' . __FUNCTION__; };
    }
}
```

Comment: but does it return the same hash when you create a 2nd reflectionfunction from the same closure? Not that I want to talk down your solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't hash `Closure` instances in a reliable manner in PHP, because you cannot access most symbols in the AST belonging to the function body.

As far as I can tell only outer scope variables used by the `Closure`, symbols in the function body of type `T_VARIABLE` (`$a`, `$b`, etc), type information and the function signature can be elucidated in a variety of ways. Absent vital information about the function body it is impossible for hash functions to behave in an idempotent manner when applied to instances of `Closure`.

`spl_object_hash` or `spl_object_id` won't save you -- a possibly (almost constantly in real world applications) changing refcount complicates the matter so these functions aren't usually idempotent either.

The only situation where hashing a `Closure` instance may be possible is when it has been defined in a PHP source file somewhere and your current instance of it uses no other `Closure` instances from its outer scope. In that case you might have some succes by wrapping your `Closure` instance in a `ReflectionFunction` instance. Now you can try to get the filename and line numbers where the `Closure` is declared. Then you could load the source file and extract the part between the line numbers, dump that part into a string and tokenize it with `token_get_all()`. Next remove tokens that don't belong to the `Closure` declaration and look at the outer scope of your `Closure` instance to get the values of any outer scope variables it uses. Finally, put all this together in some way and hash that data. But of course when you like to pass functions to functions it won't be long until you start questioning "*..but what if outer scope variables are also `Closure` instances?"* -- Well..

To test what happens in PHP I used the following a pair of functions:

```
$zhash = function ($input, callable $hash = null, callable $ob_callback = null) {
    if (\is_scalar($input)) {
        return \is_callable($hash) ? $hash($input) : \hash('md5', $input);
    }

    \ob_start(
        \is_callable($ob_callback) ? $ob_callback : null,
        4096,
        PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS
    );
    \debug_zval_dump($input);
    $dump = \ob_get_clean();

    return \is_callable($hash) ? $hash($dump) : \hash('md5', $dump);
};

$zhash_algo_gz = function ($input, string $algo = 'sha256', int $compress = -1) use ($zhash) {
    return $zhash(
        $input,
        function ($data) use ($algo) {
            return \hash($algo, $data);
        },
        function ($data) use ($compress) {
            return \gzcompress($data, $compress, ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP);
        }
    );
};
```

The use of `debug_zval_dump` was to avoid failure on circular refs and resources. The use of `gzcompress` was to compress the input data to the hash function if it was a very large class. I tested this with a fully loaded Magento2 application as input to `$zhash_algo_gz`, before I ran into the exact problems that lead me here in the first place (i.e. `debug_zval_dump` contains refcount, not function body, leading to non-idempotent results from hashing functions).

**On the the test**.

We set a variable all the closures in this test use:

```
$b = 42;
```

In the first example the refcount stays the same for both calls as our two `Closure` instances are not bound to variables and the code is executed in a fresh `php -a` session:

```
$zhash_algo_gz(function ($a) use ($b) { return $a * $b + 5; });
$zhash_algo_gz(function ($a) use ($b) { return $a * $b + 6; });
```

Output:

```
a0cd0738ea01d667c9386d4d9fe085cbc81c0010f30d826106c44a884caf6184
a0cd0738ea01d667c9386d4d9fe085cbc81c0010f30d826106c44a884caf6184
```

**Houston, we have a problem!**

As mentioned earlier we cannot infer vital information about the function body of `Closure` instances. The `+5` and `+6` tokens will not show up in any command output, `print_r`, `var_export`, `var_dump`, `debug_zval_dump` or otherwise.

This implies that hashing two anonymous functions that share the same signature, refcount, outer scope variables and parameters but a partially heterogeneous function body **will yield identical hashes**.

If we start a fresh `php -a` session, but now bind our `Closure` instances to variables first, it might look good at first glance:

```
$f1 = function ($a) use ($b) { return $a * $b + 5; });
$f2 = function ($a) use ($b) { return $a * $b + 6; });
$zhash_algo_gz($f1);
$zhash_algo_gz($f2);
```

Output:

```
085323126d01f3e04dacdbb6791f230d99f16fbf4189f98bf8d831185ef13b6c
18a9c0b26bf6f6546d08911d7268abba72e1d12ede2e9619d782deded922ab65
```

**Hey, different hashes! But don't be fooled...**

The change in hash is *not* due to the change in the function body, **it is due to the changed refcount!**. Not much use for that hash then, is there?

Apart from all this, like Brent says above, you probably want a `Class`, not a `Closure`.. this is still PHP ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use https://github.com/opis/closure ,the library is maintained and it makes use of SplObjectStorage to create an wrapper for the closure object. You can use serialize and unserialize like this:

```
use function Opis\Closure\{serialize as opisSerialize, unserialize as opisUnserialize};


    $serialized = opisSerialize(new SerializableClosure($closure));
    $wrapper = opisUnserialize($serialized);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, a simpler solution could be:

```
function GetClosureUID(closure $closure)
{
    ob_start();
    var_dump($closure);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

This worked for my use-case, but my requirements were:

- a unique string for each closure
- persistent across requests, but within a single endpoint file only, and only until the source is modified

It can be made unique across different endpoints by also including the url/file name to the returned string.

In my particular case, the following worked well:

```
function GetClosureUID(closure $closure)
{
    ob_start();
    var_dump($closure);
    $full = ob_get_clean();
    return basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .':'. substr($full, 0, strpos($full, ' ('));
};
```

But for something that is additionally persistent after modifying the source, and/or with a more descriptive string, you would need the reflection based approach.