# How to compute a unique hash for a callable

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a memoization function, and I just realized [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169500/65387) does not work when the callback is not a simple string. For example, PHP can accept a callback in the form `array($this,'memberFunc')`, which is not amenable to serialization.

Then I realized that we don't really want to hash/serialize the whole callback function/object anyway, we just need a unique ID for it so we can check for reference equality. I thought `spl_object_hash` would do the trick, but it doesn't work on arrays.

Is there another way to generate a unique reference ID for a callable?

Comment: I guess a solution would be to create a class that has a __toString() method defined, and a __call() method defined to do whatever your callback was trying to do? But that seems really hackish to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize or Hash a Closure in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983714/serialize-or-hash-a-closure-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always cast to object for hashing purposes:

```
<?php

class Foo{
    public function __construct(){
        $foo = array($this,'memberFunc');

        var_dump( spl_object_hash((object)$foo) );
        var_dump( spl_object_hash((object)$foo) );
    }
}

new Foo;
```

```
string(32) "00000000532ba9fd000000000cc9b0a5"
string(32) "00000000532ba9fd000000000cc9b0a5"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that spl_object_hash return a unique hash per execution. It can change if it deleted or in next executions

Comment: Actually this answer does not work. If you hit F5, the hash is different, so for caching purposes this breaks.

Comment: @TomasVotruba That's because of how `spl_object_hash()` works, a behaviour that `(object)` cast doesn't alter. I do not recommend such function for caching, a problem family of its own.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this function to get a hash for callables specifically:

```
/**
 * @param callable $func
 * @return string Unique string identifier for callable instance
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static function callable_hash($func) {
    if(!is_callable($func)) throw new Exception("Function must be a callable");
    if(is_string($func)) {
        return $func;
    } elseif(is_array($func)) {
        if(count($func) !== 2) throw new Exception("Array-callables must have exactly 2 elements");
        if(!is_string($func[1])) throw new Exception("Second element of array-callable must be a string function name");
        if(is_object($func[0])) return spl_object_hash($func[0]).'::'.$func[1];
        elseif(is_string($func[0])) return implode('::',$func);
        throw new Exception("First element of array-callable must be a class name or object instance");
    } elseif(is_object($func)) {
        return spl_object_hash($func);
    }
    throw new Exception("Unhandled callable type");
}
```

But if Alvaro's solution works... that's much simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Alvaro's answer, I came up with these two functions:

```
function memoized() {
    static $cache = array();
    $args = func_get_args();
    $func = array_shift($args);
    $key = sha1(serialize(array_merge(array(spl_object_hash((object)$func)),$args)));
    if(!isset($cache[$key])) {
        $cache[$key] = call_user_func_array($func, $args);
    }
    return $cache[$key];
}

function memoized_func($func) {
    return function() use ($func) {
        static $cache = array();
        $args = func_get_args();
        $key = sha1(serialize($args));
        if(!isset($cache[$key])) {
            $cache[$key] = call_user_func_array($func, $args);
        }
        return $cache[$key];
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
$f = function($n) {
    for($i=0; $i<$n; ++$i);
    return $n;
};

$result = memoized($f,50000);
$func = memoized_func($f);
$result2 = $func(50000);
```